# How can i bind repeater inside a static method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, repeater

I am Passing a parameter from client side(aspx) and in .cs file i am calling a webmethod and i can only call it only by declaring it static and i am unable to bind a repeater inside a statix method..how can i do this ..or tell me any other ways to do this.

Here is jquert code for calling webmethod

```
  function ShowPackageProduct(Id) {
        alert(Id);
        PageMethods.GetProductsInPackage(Id, function () {

        });

    }
```

and here is my .cs code

```
   public static void GetProductsInPackage(int PackageId)
    {
        Packages objpackage;
          try
        {
            objpackage = new Packages();
            objpackage.Package_id = PackageId;

            objpackage = objpackage.GetAllProductInPackage();
            //Repeater rpt = (Repeater)Page.FindControl("rptPackageDetails");
            //rpt.DataSource = objpackage;
            //rpt.DataBind();

        }
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the concept of client-side and server-side.

Comment: PageMethods are used to send and receive data, you cannot bind or refresh data in repeater.

Comment: Any aleternate for binding repater in static method

Comment: Why are you using pagemethods? Where is this jquery function called from?

Comment: this function call from aspx page

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by binding to a repeater on post back.

Let's say you define the button something like this

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="TEST" ID="ShowAll" OnClick="ShowAll_Click"/>
```

Then you define the method in the code behind

```
protected void ShowAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Bind to a repeater and other stuff

        }
```